# I got a identical Key twice in a multimap, it just exists one in the textfile.

Tags: c++, multimap

i have an issue with multimap. I read a file, that stores Years and Temepratures for everymonth.

2011   9.23    3.23   4.23    and so on.

Now i want to write the average temperature from each year back to a file.

I used a multimap. The double stores my average temps, and from my class Year i call the getYear()Method to get the Year that fits to the average temp.

I need multimap, because there are identical average temps.

But if i look now into the output file, i see that the Year 2011 is twice with the same average temp.

In the input file, the Year 2011 is just written once.

Do i get the same Year twice, because its at the and of the input file? So maybe the issue comes from reading the file in the last line?

This is how the outpuf file looks:

> 1994  9.7025
>
> 2011  9.635
>
> 2011  9.635
>
> 2002  9.55667

My stringsteam ohneKomma stores the input file.

```
while(ohneKomma)    
{  
    Year year;
    ohneKomma >> _jahr;
    year.setJahr(_jahr);

    ohneKomma >> _d1;
    ohneKomma >> _d2;
    ohneKomma >> _d3;
     //and so on....

    year.setAvgTemps(_d1, _d2, _d3, _d4, _d5, _d6, _d7, _d8, _d9, _d10, _d11, _d12);

    map2.insert(make_pair(year.getMittelwert(), year));//fallend
    ;
}
```

I hope you guys can help me and sorry for my bad english but i hope you understand what i mean :)

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of map2 ? what does year.getMittelwert() return? (my German is worse than your English)...

Comment: map2 is a multimap. and getMittelwert() returns averageTemp as double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to check for input success as the `while` condition:

```
while(ohneKomma >> jahr >> _d1 >> d2 ....)    
{  
    Year year;
    year.setJahr(_jahr);


    year.setAvgTemps(_d1, _d2, _d3, _d4, _d5, _d6, _d7, _d8, _d9, _d10, _d11, _d12);

    map2.insert(make_pair(year.getMittelwert(), year));//fallend
}
```

Comment: And also thx to you. This is a quicker way to read all the temps :)

Comment: Doubt you'll notice any performance difference - but this is the "typical" way to read from a file in C++, so I thought I'd mention it as a solution. (It will also catch certain types of  "badly formed lines" - e.g. letters where you should have numbers, which your original code doesn't necessarily cope well with - but it will just stop at that point, without any information saying why it stopped...)

Answer (score 0):

A stream does not fail until you attempt to read while at the end of the stream. You need to check the stream state after your first read operation.

```
while(ohneKomma)    
{  
    Year year;
    ohneKomma >> _jahr;
    if(!ohneKomma)
        break;
    year.setJahr(_jahr);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved it :) so 
    
    if(!ohneKomma) break; 

means i check if stringstream is empty, if yes, i break?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code as this. It will do the same but better.

```
while(ohneKomma >> _jahr)   //change here.  
{  
    Year year;
    year.setJahr(_jahr);   //note the modification here too.

    ohneKomma >> _d1;
    ohneKomma >> _d2;
    ohneKomma >> _d3;
     //and so on....

    year.setAvgTemps(_d1, _d2, _d3, _d4, _d5, _d6, _d7, _d8, _d9, _d10, _d11, _d12);

    map2.insert(make_pair(year.getMittelwert(), year));//fallend
    ;
}
```

This is the correct way to read the file, without running into weird EOF errors.